# Document vs document in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between **"Document"** and **"document"** in JavaScript.

typeof document is object which we have been using regularly in our programming & typeof Document is function.

What is the use of Document function and where to use it?

Comment: I was so ready to dismiss this question, until I started [looking in to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document).  My best guess at this point is Document() is the base class of the `document` object, but I can't find a clear statement about this yet...

Comment: See here http://www.domenlightenment.com/#2.

Comment: And here http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document

Comment: So like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gFPR9/ `var d = new Document();`?

Comment: Thank you all for your response. Got a basic idea.

Comment: @JasonSperske When i am trying var d = new Document(); in chrome console its throwing error TypeError: Illegal constructor

Answer (score 1):

A Google search gave me these results:

> The Document interface inherits from Node, and represents the whole
>   document, such as an HTML page. Although the Document node is conceptually the root of a document, it isn't physically the root - the root node is the first Element node in the Document, and is represented by its documentElement property.

From: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document

> Both Document and HTMLDocument constructors are typically instantiated
>   by the browser when you load an HTML document. However, using
>   document.implementation.createHTMLDocument() its possible to create
>   your own HTML document outside of the one currently loaded into the
>   browser. In addtion to createHTMLDocument() its also possible to
>   create a document object which has yet to be setup as an HTML document
>   using createDocument(). Typically the use of theses methods are
>   associated with programatically providing an HTML document to an
>   iframe.

From: http://www.domenlightenment.com/#2

More info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document
- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#i-Document